# Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); not mapping the statusCode of BadRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api, .net-7.0

I'm following an Udemy .NET 7 API Course and I have this strange behaviour.

Basically I have:

-A WebAPI .NET7
-An MVC Client which has a BaseService class for requesting the API.Also I have a custom class APIResponse.

Thing is, in BaseService

```
HttpResponseMessage apiResponse = await client.SendAsync(message);
var apiContent=await apiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
APIResponse ApiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIResponse>(apiContent);
```

If my API returns an Ok() or Ok(someInstance), the Deserializing works perfectly. ApiResponse has
client data in all of its properties (StatusCode,Result,ErrorMessages(as null),and IsSuccess).

But the problem is ... If I return a BadRequest(ModelState), with an ErrorMessage (using ModelState.AddMessageError("key","message"), the deserializing only instances an ApiResponse with the
ErrorMessage property. IsSuccess comes as true (default behaviour), StatusCode as 0 (since it's an int ) and Result as null. This last property it's OK, since it's a bad request.

Hope you can help me. I'll leave some classes below.

APIResponse Model

```
using System.Net;

namespace ClienteCredencialesMVC.Models
{
    public class APIResponse
    {
        public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; } 
        public bool IsSuccess { get; set; } = true;

        public List<string> ErrorMessages { get; set; }

        public object Result { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've tried debugging, but I'm not sure how it really the serializing knows how to map a client response to a custom modelClass. That's why I don't understand the BadRequest behaviour.

Comment: Check the status code of your response. Decode only if it is 200 or 201. Throw and handle an error if not.

Comment: @burnsi maybe I didn't express myself correctly. I need the 400 in my APIResponse when I serialize.

Comment: Please add an example response for both cases. If you just want your default Response with a different StatusCode don´t return BadRequest(ModelState).

Comment: @burnsi is in the right spot here. Throw a break point on your readAsStringAsync line and grab the response data you're getting for both a successful call and an unsuccessful call and add those to your OP. Most likely, the structure of the two objects will differ.

Comment: @ClearlyClueless  YES! You are both correct! The ReadAsStringAsync() returns a different model response depending on a Ok() or BadRequest(), but still don't understand why on the next line (deserialising) , the mapping works fine in the tutorial video I'm following. Maybe some custom behaviour that can be set for the BadRequest() ? Thanks guys!!

Comment: We can't really speak to that because we don't know anything about the tutorial or the bad response. If you're willing to provide examples of both the. We can probably find you a solid middle ground where both work.